How can I align high frequency time series data in microsoft excel
I have a barologger pressure time series that takes a reading every 15 minutes and a CT2X pressure time series that takes a measurement every 5 minutes. Unfortunately the time series is shifted and they don't align correctly. How can I filter my CT2X time series data so that it matches the time series of the barologger? How could I take an average of the three closest CT2X readings around the barologger time?
I have listed a picture "sample series columns" that ultimately shows what I wish to obtain.
I've tried the index-match tool in excel but I don't think I've used it correctly or if it can be done with this data.


The question is what have you tried?  There are many options... One option is to have a column that calls out the data source and in a consolidated list add everything together and sort by date/time... you can then act upon that consolidated list.

Your results do not seem to be showing "an average of the three closest CT2X readings around the barologger time". Also, your result table is showing a CT2X reading (12:36) that does not exist in your data table. Please clarify both of these discrepancies.

The screenshot I showed only looks at the first 10 rows. This is why the 12:36 CT2X reading is cut off. I could include more rows in a new screenshot if that clarifies things. Yes, youre correct that they don’t show an average of the three closest readings. This is only raw data represented in the screenshot. I was considering exploring the average option when trying to filter the CT2X data to match the barologger data in the best way possible.

Since you did not show averages as a part of what you expect for results, I chose to return a single closest value by aligning the values by

Determine the duration between a Barologger Date/Time and each of the CT2X Date/Time entries.
Set a threshold for the maximum duration allowable.

I chose two (2) minutes.


Line up the appropriate entries.

I added a line and some information to the data you provided:

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)
To use Power Query

Select some cell in your Data Table
Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range
When the PQ Editor opens: Home => Advanced Editor
Make note of the Table Name in Line 2
Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
Read the comments and explore the Applied Steps to understand the algorithm

M-CodeEdited to account for more rows in the last two columns than the first two
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Barologger DateTime (24hr)", type datetime}, {"Barologger LEVEL (cm)", type number}, {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", type datetime}, {"CT2X Pressure (psi)", type number}}),
 
//Split the tables
    Barologger = Table.Buffer(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),0,2))),
    CT2X = Table.Buffer(Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type", List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type"),2))),

//Find the matching rows
    #"Matched CT2X" = Table.Buffer(Table.AddColumn(Barologger, "Match CT2X",(r)=>
    let

    //generate a list of differences between each of the times
        difs = List.TransformMany(
                    CT2X[#"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"],
                    each {_ -r[#"Barologger DateTime (24hr)"]},
                    (a,b)=> Number.Abs(Number.From(b))),

    //determine the row numbers with the matching min times, using 2 minutes (2/1440) as the threshold
        pos = if List.Min(difs) < 2/1440
                then List.PositionOf(difs,List.Min(difs))
                else null
        in pos)),
    #"Matching CT2X" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Matched CT2X",{"Match CT2X", 
        each CT2X{_},type [#"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)"=datetime, #"CT2X Pressure (psi)"=number]}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Matching CT2X", {"Match CT2X"}),
    #"Expanded Match CT2X" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Errors", "Match CT2X", {"CT2X Date / Time (24 hour)", "CT2X Pressure (psi)"})
in
    #"Expanded Match CT2X"

Either method gives the following results from the data I posted:


Hi Ron, this was very helpful. I had one question. I have successfully inputted the code without errors and then I can view only 1000 rows within the power query window. From there I select "Close and Load" and it opens as a tab in Microsoft Excel. It shows the nicely matched time series but only a partial amount of it. There are a few thousand rows that are missing.
My data runs from 9/3/2024 to 10/17/2024 with 4,320 rows before applying the power query. After applying the power query, I'm left with 1,420 rows and data that only goes until 9/18/2024. Is there a limit to how many rows?

@WillMacKenzie 1000 rows is all you will usually see in the Power Query Editor, but the number of rows in PQ itself is limited only by available memory (in 64-bit version). The number of rows it can load to excel is the Excel row limit of 1,048,576 rows. So that is not what is limiting. Could there be slippage in your data where after 9/18/2024 none of your every 5 min times are within 2 minutes of the every 15 minute times? Maybe you need to alter that variable.

Thank you Ron for your help. It seems that I had made a mistake with the amount of data. I've figured it out by examining the timing.

Hi Ron, so I tried running this code on the section after the 1,409 rows to see if it would work. It seems that I cannot run the code as it keeps sending me an "[Expression.Error] We cannot convert the value null to type logical."
I don't believe that there is a slippage in the timeseries as it is continuous data and was left untouched. If I sent you a copy of my working excel file would you be able to help me?

@WillMacKenzie Upload it to some site like OneDrive, DropBox, or Google Drive, and post a link to it here. Be sure to grant permission to download the file, if that is an option.

Here is the link below:
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Ak191u6-a-c7gVlLjn0QdOTiQVTI?e=8f8qVg

@WillMacKenzie The reason for only 1420 rows is because, you were only selecting the first 4230 rows of your data. Those are the Barologger rows. However, the CT2X columns have over 12,000 rows, so nothing after 9/18/2024  4:01:51 AM is available to be matched. The reason for the null error has to do with those blank rows in the first two columns of your data. You did not show that as a possibility in your example, and my Power Query code did not take that into account. I will edit the code in my answer for that. And I will see if there is any way to speed things up.

@WillMacKenzie See the speedy version in your other identical question.
